# Is there a way to configure a local mercurial repository to stop it from being able to push to a remote repository?

Tags: version-control, mercurial

In git, there is a common practice of removing push access to the upstream repository for teams which use a specific workflow. This can be accomplished [with a simple command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10260311/git-how-to-disable-push) to change the configuration. This keeps developers from accidentally pushing up changes without the proper review process. It still allows users to pull the latest changes from that repository.

Is there a way to configure a local mercurial repository to stop it from being able to push to a remote [read-only] repository?

Comment: About this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37718008/mercurial-how-to-disable-push

Comment: @MarcosZolnowski not quite the same. That is asking for a configuration change on the remote repo side to disallow all pushes for any reason. I'm asking for a change on the local repo side to disallow pushes from this specific local repo to another specific remote repo.

Answer (score 1):

You have at least two ways: local and remote

### Remote-repo type

On push-target add `pretxnchangegroup` hook, which reject pushes (all or some), easiest form

```
#!/bin/sh
echo 'No pushes here'
exit 1
```

### Local type

Add [alias](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/doc/hgrc.5.html#alias), which redefine push into "something" without real push, but note the note in docs

> It is possible to create aliases with the same names as existing
>   commands, which will then override the original definitions. This is
>   almost always a bad idea!

Comment: How do you actually go about adding the hook you mentioned?

Comment: @DaveInCaz - obviously http://hgbook.red-bean.com/read/handling-repository-events-with-hooks.html#sec:hook:simple write into target's hgrc